# How to wait 1 second in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

```
frame = ttk.Frame(win, width=1000, height=55)  # set your desired dimensions here
    frame.pack(expand=True, fill='none')
    frame.pack_propagate(False)  # allows you to explicitly set the dimensions of the frame
    progbar = ttk.Progressbar(frame, mode='determinate', maximum=100)  # example progress bar!
    progbar.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    progbar.start(10)
    progbar.after(1000,progbar.stop())
```

I want to make a program that starts a progressbar and closes it after one second, but when I run the app, the program freezes one second and doesn't start the progressbar

Comment: Remove the `()` after `progbar.stop`. You call it immediately instead of letting it call later through `after`.